# Javascript toFixed() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to format the user input values using following technique, but I get the following error on Fire Bug console

$(this).val().toFixed is not a function

```
$(".amount-text").bind('change',function () { 
     $(this).val(($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns a string, to use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) on a number you'll need to parse it into a Number first, like this:

```
$(".amount-text").bind('change',function () { 
     $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

Or with jQuery 1.4+, a bit cleaner, at least to me [use a function with `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2):

```
$(".amount-text").bind('change',function () { 
     $(this).val(function(i, v) { return parseFloat(v).toFixed(2); });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/NcZ5r/1/).

Comment: When I use the function, it returns an object.

Answer (score 6):

`toFixed` only works on a number, parse the value to a number first:

```
 $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `val()` returns a `String` rather than a `Number`. To be able to use `toFixed()`, do something like:

```
$(".amount-text").bind('change',function () { 
     $(this).val( (parseFloat($(this).val())).toFixed(2) );
});
```

or even:

```
$(".amount-text").bind('change',function () { 
     $(this).val( (new Number($(this).val())).toFixed(2) );
});
```

You may also be able to do it slightly more hackily as:

```
$(".amount-text").bind('change',function () { 
     $(this).val( (0 + $(this).val()).toFixed(2) );
});
```

but I don't recommend it for readability purposes!

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 added the property `valueAsNumber` to the `input` element, so you don't need to apply `parseFloat` by yourself. ([Documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement))